# How to add color to a little bit of XML string resource, in Android?

Tags: android, xml

I want to show a programming tutorial. A little code a little explanation, and so on. I want to display the code in some other color. The trouble is: I have dozens of different tutorials.

I can't go around making separate activities for each of them with a little normal text in one textview, a little colored text in another one, that's just terrible, plus I'd then have like 30 textviews.

```
<string name="sbegw">
   Normal Text. 
   <some color tag="#012345"> Colored Text </some color tag>
</string>
```

This is what I'm looking for: an attribute that I can simply insert in my string resource at places where I want it.

The normal text above should appear normally, and the colored text should be colored (obviously). I have tried several attributes, I can't even get some text to look "Bold" or underlined using `<b></b>` or `<u></u>` or something like this?

Is any formatting possible in XML? Or can I only get plain boring text?

Is something like this possible in XML (Android)? How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style text using HTML tags in your strings resource file, you need to call HTML.fromHtml(getString(R.id.stringWithStyleTags)) in your code wherever you are displaying the string, where R.id.stringWithStyleTags is some string resource with HTML tags. So if it were in some textview it would look like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container);
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    // style text in TextView based on HTML tags in string resource
    tv.setText(HTML.fromHtml(getString(R.id.stringWithStyleTags)));
}
```

Here are the available HTML tags for TextViews:

http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

Comment: Thank you for answering, but uhhh Doing this will change the whole string used in that particular textview, which is exactly what I don't want. I'm showing, say a little black text, a little blue text and then black again (Explanation then code and then explanation again) ...So I really don't think having 40 textviews is the best answer... I want partly color the XML string resource.

Comment: @user2621649 I think this is exactly what you need then. You can use the HTML tags in certain parts of your strings, meaning you could do multiple styles and colors. So in your strings.xml: <string name="example"><font color=”#0000FF”><b>This is bold and blue.</b></font> <font color=”#FF0000”><u>And this is red and underlined.</u></font></string> ...then you pass the string into the method i said above. I believe this is exactly what you are looking for. Please accept my answer if it is. Thanks, and good luck!

Answer (score -1):

create your own style and give that style to your textview:

**styles.xml**

```
  <style name="yourtheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FA8072</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:text">Colored Text</item>
</style>
```

**TextView**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/thankyou"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/yourtheme"
        />
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but uhhh Doing this will change the whole string used in that particular textview, which is exactly what I don't want. I'm showing, say a little black text, a little blue text and then black again (Explanation then code and then explanation again) ...So I really don't think having 40 textviews is the best answer... I want partly color the XML string resource.

Comment: So you want that some specific string or word have unique color?

Comment: Yes !,Example:- "How are you".... I want the "are" to be colored....without using 3 textviews to do this. I need a way to just change a little bit of the string in the XML itself .... Any idea ?